# Excel index match in SQL - lookup a value from a matrix

Tags: sql, matrix, indexing, match, lookup

I'm trying to perform somethign similar to an excel index match in SQL.

I have a matrix looking like the below:

Matrix in excel:

[image: Matrix in excel]

This is made by variable Pers (vertical) and variable Contribution (horizontal) where 5-6-7-8-9-10 are values the variable contribution can take. this is just for illustration purposes, my matrix is 72 columns per 165 rows for a total of 11644 cells (Universe of possible values).

Through those 2 variables I need to extract for any ID the cell 'value' inside the matrix. an example below of the desired output:

Output in excel:

[image: Output in excel]

I can make this in excel via index match but I would like to import this matrix in SQL and make the lookup in there so the calculation can be dynamic because I have always new IDs with their own 'pers' and 'contribution' that will need to be associated with a value in that matrix, therefore it's inefficient to extract the IDs from SQL to make the calculation in excel to then import it into SQL again.
obviously I can't use a 'case when' because I have 11644 cases which would be a suicide to write/read
is there anything in SQL that can perform anything similar to index-match?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: It'd be good to have more details on the tables, could you post your table definitions? On creating a very big sql statement: there are techniques to generate the complete or parts  of the sql statement. You could even create the sql statement in Excel and so using your information to generate all of the case statements. That being said, very big sqls are kind of an anti-pattern. Creating a good sql requires knowing more about the struture of the tables.

Comment: Hello, pers are 165 characteristics that the ID can take and contribution is a figure that represents the contribution that can be given, there are 72 possible contributions. Value, output, is the assessed value for that ID. I normally create my case statement sin excel anyway but I would like to avoid to have a case statement 11644 long if I can. cheers

Comment: I suggest creating the base structure and maybe add some data in a db-fiddle for example at https://dbfiddle.uk/ then linking it in the question. That way finding a viable solution would be much easier.

Comment: ok thanks, For the moment what I'm going to do is to transform the matrix into a table in excel, where is easier, and uploading the table in SQL where I can perform just a join with the IDs